# Vim problem with gf command

Tags: vim

I am using [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) and I have set the path (`set path+= c:/work/etc/etc`) to my project directory (for C#), but still using command 'gf' give me error:

> E:447 Can't find file.

Is there anything I am doing wrong over here?

Comment: I always have problems when I try to command my gf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First can you open the file using **:find file.name** ? (**:help find** for more info). If this does not work then your path is wrong. If **:find** does locate your file then do the following:

1. Insure that you are not in **Visual/Insert** mode
2. Place cursor on the first letter of the filename and press **gf**

Answer (score 17):

G'day,

To get a bit more detail on your current path settings you can see what's being included and the files vim can't find by entering the command:

```
:checkpath
```

and you'll get a dump of the files not found, e.g.

```
--- Included files not found in path --- 
<io.h> 
vim.h --> 
  <functions.h> 
  <clib/exec_protos.h>
```

Or you can get a listing of all included files, both found and not found, by entering

```
:checkpath!
```

Enter

```
:help path
```

to get more info on the path syntax.

**Edit:** Don't forget that using the syntax

```
set path=/work
```

will completely reset your path variable to what you've just declared. I'd suggest using

```
set path+=/work
```

instead. This won't clobber the current path and will just add your /work directory instead.

HTH

Comment: I tried to use checkpath and its give me message "All included files were found". and yes i used set path += mypath.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I also found out that

```
:set path+=./foo/bar
```

adds a search location relative to the directory of the current file, just like '.' does.

My vim didn't want to search for such include

```
#include <common/util/string.h>
```

So what I needed to do was

```
:set path+=foo/bar
```

instead of

```
:set path+=./foo/bar
```

The former adds a search path relative to current working directory. Hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I also had some troubles with this for another reason and it took me some time to find out why. I hope this might be helpful to someone.

When a directory is matched with `wildignore`, `gf` does not work for files in it, nor does :find.

This is obvious if you read wildignore's documentation, but I forgot I ever changed this variable, and what it was for exactly. Also I used a glob, and it was not immediately apparent to me that the directory I was using gf in, was also matched with this glob.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no leading character to the file name if you press `gf`, i.e. using `gf` when the cursor is on help.txt will not work here:

```
file=help.txt
```

Comment: maybe I can mark the file in visual mode as a preparation step?

Answer (score -4):

## If you are talking about the ***`gf` tool wri††en by tomnomnom*** then here's how to set-up:

**Setting PATH for GO** (if you have not setup yet).

```
export GOROOT=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Step 1: **Download tool** from [github](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gf.git)

Step 2: `cp -r path/to/tomnomnom/gf/examples ~/.gf`

Step 3: `source ~/tools/gf/gf-completion.bash`

Now gf should work along with auto-completion from anywhere.
Source: Original sources are present at his [repo.](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gf)